# How to use Fermat's little theorem to solve this problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(25^{1202} + 3)^2$ mod $61$

I know to how solve the form of $a^{p-1}$ mod $p$, but don't know how to reduce $(25^{1202} + 3)^2$ into the form.

Comment: Use the formula $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ and you are good.

Comment: You could simplify the $25^{1202} $ inside the parentheses first, using $25^{60}=1$ since $1202=60k+2.$

Comment: ...or you can work the other way.  If a = x mod p then a + b = x + b = y mod p and (a+b)^m = y^m mod p.  But cr001's suggestion is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fermat's Little theorem, we have 
$25^{60} \equiv 1 \pmod {61}$
$\left(25^{60}\right)^{20} \equiv 1^{20} \pmod {61}$
$25^{1200} \equiv 1 \pmod {61}$
$25^{1202} \equiv 25^2 \equiv 625 \equiv 15 \pmod {61}$
$25^{1202}+3 \equiv 18 \pmod {61}$
$\left(25^{1202}+3\right)^2 \equiv 18^2 \equiv 324 \equiv19 \pmod {61}$
$\left(25^{1202}+3\right)^2 \equiv19 \pmod {61}$

The answer is $19$.

Answer (score 0):

Reducion modulo $61$ is a ring homomorphism, hence
$$\bigl(25^{1202}+3\bigr)^2=\bigl(5^{2404}+3\bigr)^2\equiv\bigl(5^{2404\bmod60}+3\bigr)^2=628^2\equiv 18^2=324\equiv19\mod61.$$